# Really slow response from Strapi API

Tags: strapi

System

Node.js version: v12.16

NPM version: 6.14.6

Strapi version: 3.1.4

Database: mongo atlas

Operating system: windows 10

I'm making a simple blog which I deployed to netlify, https://highlive.netlify.app/ . I would like to know why it takes so long to load the content . I have a collection type called Post and it has 10 fields which two of them is related to categories and tags. I don't know if it helps but I deployed strapi on Heroku. I would really appreciate if someone could help me to figure out why is this happening because I have just 13 posts on my Post's collection.

Answer (score 1):

I found the root of the problem ! It's not a Strapi issue. What's happening is that my dyno on Heroku goes to sleep after 1 hour without traffic.

Comment: So how did you fix that

Comment: In my case I've used node-cron to ping my heroku app. There are another ways. You can check here if you are interested https://genicsblog.com/gouravkhunger/8-ways-to-keep-your-heroku-app-awake